# Loading component after fetch in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, promise

I'm trying to consume an API using axios.

This is my code until now:

```
<select>
    <option v-for="value in values"> value.name </option>
</select>

   // js
   data(){
        values: [],
   },
   created() {
        this.getData();
   },

   methods: {
       getData: () => {
          axios.get('url')
          .then(res => {
              this.value = res.data.dados;
              console.log(res.data.dados);
          })
          .catch(error => {
               console.log(error);
          });
   }
}
```

The promise's `console.log` is working normally, but the options with data isn't rendered.
It's probably because my select component is being rendered before the 'getData()'. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've a typo on `this.value`, it should be `this.values`. If that doesn't work, use `this.$forceUpdate()` to force re-render component

```
<select>
    <option v-for="value in values">{{ value.name }}</option>
</select>

   // js
   data(){
        values: [],
   },
   created() {
        this.getData();
   },

   methods: {
       getData: () => {
          axios.get('url')
          .then(res => {
              this.values = res.data.dados; // change value to values
              console.log(res.data.dados);
              this.$forceUpdate(); // add forceUpdate
          })
          .catch(error => {
               console.log(error);
          });
   }
}
```

Comment: It was not the typo.  Now, it says "TypeError: _this.$forceUpdate is not a function
    at eval (Pesquisa.vue?cddd:49)"

Comment: have you try change the `this.value` to `this.values` ?

Comment: oh the forceUpdate error because the function called upon created, you can change it to mounted

Answer (score 2):

Just put a loading handler.

```
<select v-if="loaded">
  <option v-for="value in values"> value.name </option>
</select>

   // js
   data(){
        values: [],
        loaded: false,
   },
   created() {
        this.getData();
   },

   methods: {
       getData: () => {
          axios.get('url')
          .then(res => {
              this.value = res.data.dados;
              this.loaded = true;
          })
          .catch(error => {
               console.log(error);
               this.loaded = true;
          });
   }
}
```